# Python import vs direct execution

Tags: python, python-import

```
#conf.py

def init():
    global mylist   
    mylist=[]


#change.py

import conf

def change():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print('Direct')
        conf.mylist.append('Directly executed')
        print(conf.mylist)
    else:
        conf.mylist.append('It was imported') 


#exec.py

import conf
import change

conf.init()  
change.change()

print (conf.mylist)
```

When running *exec.py* the result is what I expected, **but** when running *change.py* directly I didn't get any output (no *Direct* , no `conf.mylist`)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's the normal behavior. You need to call the `change` function for this code to execute.

You can add the following to the end of *change.py*

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    change()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `change` is never invoked. Invoke it at the end of the file with `change()`